# Reversing a sentence in java

Tags: java

am doing this challenge of reversing a  given sentence at https://www.codewars.com/kata/reversed-words/train/java ,,,I have already managed to reverse the sentence to the expected but am getting a slight error in their JUnit testing..
this is my code to reverse any sentence to the expected result e.g

> "The greatest victory is that which requires no battle"
>   // should return "battle no requires which that is victory greatest The"

**My code**

```
    public class ReverseWords{
 public static String reverseWords(String sentence){
   String reversedsentence ="";

       for(int x=sentence.length()-1;x>=0;--x){  //Reversing the whole sentence                                                           

            reversedsentence += sentence.charAt(x);                       
       } //now you are assured the whole sentence is reversed

       String[]words = reversedsentence.split(" "); //getting each word in the  reversed sentence and storing it in a string array

       String ExpectedSentence= "";
        for(int y=0;y<words.length;y++){
            String word =words[y];   //getting word by word in the  string array

            String reverseWord = "";
            for(int j=word.length()-1;j>=0;j--){    /*Reversing each word  */

                 reverseWord += word.charAt(j);    
            }
            ExpectedSentence +=reverseWord + " ";   //adding up the words to get the expected sentence

        }

            return ExpectedSentence;
    }
}
```

and there JUnit testing code

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

// TODO: Replace examples and use TDD development by writing your own tests

public class SolutionTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
         assertEquals(ReverseWords.reverseWords("I like eating"), "eating like I");
         assertEquals(ReverseWords.reverseWords("I like flying"), "flying like I");
         assertEquals(ReverseWords.reverseWords("The world is nice"), "nice is world The");
    }
}
```

The Error am getting

```
> expected:<eating like I[ ]> but was:<eating like I[]>
```

**More details about the error are**

```
> org.junit.ComparisonFailure:  expected:<eating like I[ ]> but was:<eating like I[]>   at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)   at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)   at SolutionTest.testSomething(SolutionTest.java:10)
```

You can simply follow this link and paste **my code** you will see a code play ground [Train: Reversed Words |CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reversed-words/train/java)

Comment: Remove the ending space character once your loop is over. Naming a variable starting with a capital char doesn't respect Java naming convention

Comment: @sarkasronie Sorry, my bad.

Comment: where specifically,,where should  I remove the ending space character

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Assert.assertEquals("sentence a is This", reverseSentence("This is a sentence"));
}


public static String reverseSentence(String sentence) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length / 2; i++) {
        String temp = words[i];
        words[i] = words[words.length - i - 1];
        words[words.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return String.join(" ", words);
}
```

With `String.join()` you skip the hassle to avoid adding the delimiter to the last element.

Comment: it has not worked bro,,,am still getting the previous mistake

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The above sample does work. Please check for any input errors.

Comment: No reason to allocate `String[]` with `split()`. Sure it works, but it's not a clean approach.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I would not know how to solve this in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

First you are using `Assert.assertEquals()` incorrectly because `expected` parameter should be provided first. Change it to:

```
assertEquals("eating like I", ReverseWords.reverseWords("I like eating"));
```

which makes the error clear:

```
> expected:<eating like I[]> but was:<eating like I[ ]>
```

This is caused by following line which blindly adds the space after each `reverseWord` processed:

```
ExpectedSentence +=reverseWord + " ";   //adding up the words to get the expected sentence
```

Comment: hey @Karol the Assert.assertEquals() am not the one who made its the guy who came up with  this challenge...how do i make sure the last word is not  added " "?

Comment: If you want a hack use `return ExpectedSentence.trim()`. A better solution would be to use `StringBuilder` and keep track of the spaces that are being processed.